# how to make gradient with 3 colors and degree 141 in android

Tags: android, xml

I have the following css 
background: linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);

I need to implement the previous css using android

I tried the following but it give me empty gradient

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#0fb8ad"
                android:endColor="#2cb5e8"
                android:centerColor="#1fc8db"
                android:type="radial" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:startColor="#000fb8ad"
        android:endColor="#802cb5e8"
        android:centerColor="#c01fc8db"/>

</shape>
```

I'm using the alpha channel to simulate the percentages from your original: `00` is 0%, `80` is 50%, and `C0` is 75%.

Gradient angles must be a multiple of 45 degress in Android, so I've used 135 instead of 141.

Don't specify `android:type="radial"`; just use the default (linear).